# In Russian, how do you say "shall we say, graduated" euphemistically?

Tags: перевод

> I’ve...**shall we say, *graduated*** from my life as a hacker.

I want to say this in Russian, and I'm not sure how to idiomatically express the "shall we say, *graduated*" bit with euphemism. Rather than putting it bluntly: "I've quit", the verb "graduated" is used euphemistically here, which is signalled by the preceding phrase "shall we say".

> Компьютерным взломом  я больше не занимаюсь.

I think this phrasing is rather straightforward and does not fully express the idea conveyed by the English phrase. I wonder if the verb "окончить" gets the job done for this figurative meaning.

Answer (score 9):

*Я, скажем так, переболел хакерством*

This verb is usually applied to childhood infections like chickenpox or rubella which before the advent of vaccines most kids got early in their lives and once it had been over they were immune to this infection.

In modern Russian it's a metaphor for "going though a phase":

> - Надеюсь. этими "детскими болезнями" телевидение переболеет и профессионализм снова будет в цене. [Федор Чеханков: Ненависть меня разрушает (2002) // «Витрина читающей России», 2002.09.13]
> - а вот мистика пострашней ИМХО. мой
>     мой в своё время читал Кинга. я была в шоке. но ниче, переболел, щас ваще его не воспринимает. это же может быть издержки определённого возраста. пока думаю, дёргаться не стоит, а вот в курсе быть надо. [Наши дети: Подростки (2004)]
> - Но вот удивительно — компьютерными играми с тех пор навсегда переболел. [Майя Кучерская. Современный патерик: чтение для впавших в уныние (2004)]

Comment: best equivalent in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

The first that comes into mind is завязал. The second is поставил крест. The third is развязался. All of them are synonymous to покончил. I think there are more.

> С хакерством я завязал/покончил/развязался. На хакерстве я, скажем, поставил крест.

Answer (score 0):

> (Ну,) я, скажем так, с хакерством завязал/покончил <sup>(higher register)</sup> || Хакерство для меня - это, скажем так, пройденный этап

OR

> (Ну,) с хакерством я, скажем так, завязал/покончил

OR

> (Ну,) с хакерством я завязал/покончил, скажем так/назовём это так || Хакерство для меня - это пройденный этап, скажем так/назовём это так

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no well-recognised euphemism for what you want to express (actually, you'd want to "translate" the "shall we say" part, not the "graduated" part).

All the variants with "скажем/скажем так" (almost surely) won't work without the "wink, wink, nudge, nudge"-ing or heavily intoning these words. I'd suggest using somewhat more modern-streetish "как бы" ("so to say, in a way"; e.g., "*как бы* покончил"), but that, too, is intonation-dependent (try to stretch the marked words).

UPDATE: Actually, scratch that answer, I've misread your question. Apologies.

Comment: Not at all ! Because the "shall we say" part is important, too.